# Custom JFrame movement "slipping"

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Recently, I have been trying to make my gui's look good and part of it is implementing my own titlebar, maximize button, minimize button, etc.

I am having issues on the dragging, I want to be able to drag the JFrame by clicking anywhere in it.

I attempted to create a mousemotionlistener to handle it however it slips when I use it. As in I attempt to drag the window to a location however it appears to be skipping calls to mouseDragged and attempting to call mouseMoved instead.

Here is my code

```
public class MouseWindowDragManager implements MouseMotionListener{
    private JFrame frame;
    int prevPosX = -1;
    int prevPosY = -1;

    public MouseWindowDragManager(JFrame frame){
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int newX = (frame.getLocation().x + (e.getXOnScreen() - prevPosX));
        int newY = (frame.getLocation().y + (e.getYOnScreen() - prevPosY));
        frame.setLocation(newX, newY);
        prevPosX = e.getXOnScreen();
        prevPosY = e.getYOnScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        prevPosX = e.getXOnScreen();
        prevPosY = e.getProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", true);tYOnScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to that it's being interfered with by other mouse listeners registered within the application.  Components higher up in the hierarcy will block mouse events to components lower in the hierarcy

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is currently the only mouselistener (really any listener at all) on the jframe. Thank you trying though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Recently, I have been trying to make my gui's look good and part of it is implementing my own titlebar, maximize button, minimize button, etc.

Gee, Microsoft and Apple spend millions of dollars to develop GUI's that users can use. They will be disappointed to hear this :)

> I want to be able to drag the JFrame by clicking anywhere in it.

Check out [Moving Windows](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a class that allows you to drag a window around. The example code shows how to use the class by just dragging on your custom title bar. However, if you really want to be able to drag the frame by clicking anywhere then you can register the frame's `root pane` with the `ComponentMover`.